# MVCSiteMapProvider ignore parameters

Tags: asp.net, mvcsitemapprovider

I am using MVCSiteMapProvider.MVC5 and I am trying to set up my site map.

My routes are:

notifications/

notifications/Alarm/

notifications/Warning/

notifications/Information/

The Alarm, Warning and Information are passed to the "notificationFilter" action parameter.

This is my basic site map which currently shows by breadcrumb for route notifications/ as Home>Notifications.

```
  <mvcSiteMapNode title="Home" controller="Dashboard" action="System">
     <mvcSiteMapNode title="Vacuum Management" controller="Dashboard" action="SubSystem" />
     <mvcSiteMapNode title="Notifications" controller="Notifications" action="SystemNotifications" />
 </mvcSiteMapNode>
```

What I would like to do is add a catch all so that if the "notificationFilter" parameter is passed (e.g. notifications/Alarm/) it still displays the breadcrumb as Home>Notifications and ignores the parameter.

I have tried this:

```
  <mvcSiteMapNode title="Home" controller="Dashboard" action="System">
     <mvcSiteMapNode title="Vacuum Management" controller="Dashboard" action="SubSystem" />
     <mvcSiteMapNode title="Notifications" controller="Notifications" action="SystemNotifications" notificationFilter="Alarm" />
```

Which works for notifications/Alarm but then nothing else. I also tried adding multiple lines:

```
  <mvcSiteMapNode title="Home" controller="Dashboard" action="System">
     <mvcSiteMapNode title="Vacuum Management" controller="Dashboard" action="SubSystem" />
     <mvcSiteMapNode title="Notifications" controller="Notifications" action="SystemNotifications" notificationFilter="Alarm" />
     <mvcSiteMapNode title="Notifications" controller="Notifications" action="SystemNotifications" notificationFilter="Warning" />
     <mvcSiteMapNode title="Notifications" controller="Notifications" action="SystemNotifications" notificationFilter="Information" />
```

But because the title is the key the the bread crumb would display different text.

All help appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Route Config:

```
            routes.MapRoute(
            name: "NotificationsSystem",
            url: "notifications",
            defaults: new { controller = "Notifications", action = "SystemNotifications", notificationFilter = "" }
            );

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "NotificationsSystemFiltered",
            url: "notifications/{notificationFilter}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Notifications", action = "SystemNotifications", notificationFilter = "" }
            );
```

Comment: Typically, the route values are used to match the route values of the request (not the URL). But you have not posted your route configuration so it is not possible to tell if they match or not (which I suspect they don't). Please post your routing configuration.

Comment: Thanks NightOwl888 I have added my route config above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per [the documentation](https://github.com/maartenba/MvcSiteMapProvider/wiki/Routing-Basics#preservedrouteparameters-attribute), getting a single node to match *any* value for a particular parameter can be done by using `preservedRouteParameters`.

```
<mvcSiteMapNode title="Notifications" controller="Notifications" action="SystemNotifications" preservedRouteParameters="notificationFilter" />
```

This works well when your node has no children, but if you put this attribute on nodes that do have children you need to [take into consideration what will happen when the user navigates back up the hierarchy](http://www.shiningtreasures.com/post/2013/09/02/how-to-make-mvcsitemapprovider-remember-a-user-position#forcing-a-match).